# Restarting a program with a key word - re looping?

Tags: c++, function, loops

So I've made a program in class for a project, this is done using C++, which is a menu system with one sub menu, to then deliver correct directions from one location to another,
this involved many else and if statements as well as a while loop. however, i'm wondering if it is at all possible to make it so if the user enters a particular string, to restart from the beginning of the program? such as a small function which is a re director to the top of the code again? so if the user messes up on the first menu, they can type 'back' in and go back to the previous menu?

it sounds easy, and its simple, but i'm having trouble with it, and don't know what the best way to approach this would be, despite how minor it is!

Any help is appreciated

thanks!

Comment: You could use a boolean, to be set to false when the string is entered, as additional loop condition for all inner loops and wrap all code in another loop.

Comment: Without showing a shell of your code it is hard to suggest a method to do this.  Post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).